# Ensure a method is called from another?

Tags: archunit

I have a layer, call it `Service` and another called `Permission`. I was wondering if I could enforce a rule that says:

From within any public method of any public class within `Service` layer whose parameter list contains a parameter named `foo`, assert that it calls a method from `Permission` layer (and ideally, ensure it is called before anything else within the `Service` layer).

Is this possible with ArchUnit?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work out of the box but you can achieve that goal with the following solution:

```
DescribedPredicate<JavaClass> isPermissionClass = JavaClass.Predicates
    .resideInAnyPackage("..permission..");

classes()
    .that().resideInAnyPackage("..service..")
    .should(new ContainOnlyMethodsCallingPermissionClass(isPermissionClass));
```

`ContainOnlyMethodsCallingPermissionClass` can be defined as follows. It first collects all declared methods and then checks whether outgoing method calls to permission classes cover all collected methods.

```
public static class ContainOnlyMethodsCallingPermissionClass extends ArchCondition<JavaClass> {

    private final DescribedPredicate<JavaClass> isPermissionClass;

    public ContainOnlyMethodsCallingPermissionClass(DescribedPredicate<JavaClass> isPermissionClass) {
        super("only contain methods calling a permission class");
        this.isPermissionClass = isPermissionClass;
    }

    @Override
    public void check(JavaClass javaClass, ConditionEvents events) {
        Set<String> methodIdentifiers = getMethodIdentifiersOfClass(javaClass);
        methodIdentifiers.removeAll(collectMethodsCallingPermissionClass(javaClass));

        for (String methodId : methodIdentifiers) {
            events.add(new SimpleConditionEvent(javaClass, false, methodId));
        }
    }

    private Set<String> collectMethodsCallingPermissionClass(JavaClass javaClass) {
        Set<String> methodIdentifiers = new HashSet<>();

        for (JavaAccess<?> access : javaClass.getAccessesFromSelf()) {
            if (!isCallFromMethod(access)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (isMethodCallToPermissionClass(access)) {
                JavaMethod callingMethod = (JavaMethod) access.getOwner();
                methodIdentifiers.remove(callingMethod.getFullName());
            }
        }

        return methodIdentifiers;
    }

    private Set<String> getMethodIdentifiersOfClass(JavaClass javaClass) {
        return javaClass.getMethods().stream().filter(method -> !method.isConstructor())
                .map(method -> method.getFullName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    private boolean isCallFromMethod(JavaAccess<?> access) {
        return access.getOrigin() instanceof JavaMethod;
    }

    private boolean isMethodCallToPermissionClass(JavaAccess<?> access) {
        return isPermissionClass.apply(access.getTargetOwner());
    }
}
```

You can also change the predicate operating on `JavaClass`es to one operating on `JavaMethodCall`s for locating relevant permission methods more precisely. This additionally allows filtering out irrelevant methods in the service layer (e.g., `toString()` methods).